# Swift - fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints - return space when there's no character

Tags: swift, label, tap

I am using a tap gesture to detect tapped words in a label, and I'm using:

```
let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
```

To check if the tapped character is in the range. The problem is that the text is centered, and the word that needs to be detected on tap is the only word in the center of the line, and the code above detects the spaces on the side of the word as the first character and last character of the word. This is because of the documentation of Apple on this for

```
`func characterIndex(for point: CGPoint, in container: NSTextContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints partialFraction: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>?) -> Int:`
```

> Analogous to glyphIndex(for:in:fractionOfDistanceThroughGlyph:), but expressed in character index terms. The method returns the index of the character falling under point, expressed in coordinate system of container; if no character is under the point, the nearest character is returned

I need to change this so that when no character is under the point to return a space or something, I can detect that.

Comment: So you have the index of the tapped character. You can use `range(of:)` on string (or attributed string) to get the range of text and check whether `indexOfCharacter` is inside that range. Or have I misunderstood your problem?